# Problema al cambiar fondo de un div - Wordpress y Astra

Tags: css, wordpress

Estoy intentando cambiar el fondo de un div concreto en una entrada de wordpress. Para ello, como he hecho en otros temas, cree una clase, y le asigne las propiedades css en un tema hijo. Sin embargo, parece que el tema Astra no me permite cambiar el fondo completo, sino solo de una parte, quedando así.

[image: Así se ve la página actualmente.]

La idea es que la zona azul cubra todo lo blanco horrizontalmente, pues la parte vertical ya está como quiero. No quiero modificar las propiedades del editor Astra de la página (cambiar de recuadro a estirado), ya que tendría que crear varias clases nuevas para simular eso. También preferiría evitar usar JS, ya que necesito tener la mayor velocidad posible en esta entrada.

Actualmente, la clase está definida así (aunque también he probado con vh y vw, sin éxito)

```
.blue-area{
background-color: #e6f2ff;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}
```

¿Cómo podría reescribir las propiedades CSS para arreglarlo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que la clase creada solo engloba el contenido del texto, mas no el contenedor en si, verifica cual es el contenedor que engloba todo y agrega a dicho contenedor tu clase

Comment: El problema está en que el bloque superior ya sería el entry-content...si le aplico la clase ahí, estaría en todas las entradas, y no solo en este div concreto.

Comment: En ese caso asígnale los estilos a entry-content pero usando como selector una clase unica, si te vas a body veras que hay una serie de clases, dos de ellas son las importantes, single y post-id, usa algo como .post-tu-id .entry-content {} y agregale a ese los estilos, de esa forma estas editando el entry-content clase pero solo de el post actual

Comment: Perfecto, con eso cambie el color de toda la entrada a azul, aunque no solo el de la sección específica. Aunque no era exactamente lo que buscaba, entre eso y algun que otro apaño pude tener un resultado similar que creo que ya queda bien. ¡Gracias!